What is a replacement method for newClassPathResource in Jetty?
I am working on upgrading Jetty in Apache Drill from version 9 to version 12.  I'm not a Jetty expert but have been able to figure out most of the changes.  However, I'm stuck on the following code:
InputStream optionsDescribeTemplateStream = Resource.newClassPathResource(OPTIONS_DESCRIBE_TEMPLATE_JS).getInputStream();

The newClassPathResource was deprecated and Google searches and even ChatGPT have not been able to point me in the direction of a suitable replacement.
What is the new way of obtaining the correct path for a file contained within the class path?  Thanks!!
